# .NET Web API Allow one instance to execute a method while other instances wait and resume

Tags: asp.net

**Problem:**

I have a Controller that relies on a token from another service, and this token must be renewed periodically. I have a limited number of requests to renew the token, and it's crucial to ensure that token renewal is performed only when necessary.

```
  1      2       3
  |      |       |
  |     wait    wait
renew    |       |  
  |    resume  resume
  |      |       |
```

**What needs to be achieved:**

A Controller executes the method, which renews the token, all the other controllers wait until its execution then resume. The idea is that all the Controllers will use the updated value and the renewal was not requested by multiple instances.

Based on my understanding, Controllers are independent instances recreated on each request. I'm uncertain if this can even be achieved, but I hope for the best.

Comment: on single server - mutex in singleton, in multi server - distributed locking, for example with redis